# Socket replacement wiring

Tags: wiring, socket

[image][image]

Hi all, 2nd and final request today, this one is a replacement socket, But again the internal wiring isn't looking particularly normal. Any help will be great. I'm in the UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to connect:

- Red to the 'L' terminal (brown)
- Black to the 'N' terminal (blue)
- Green to the earth terminal (green / yellow)

Your wiring is the in old colour scheme and the socket is marked with the new (harmonised) colour scheme.

(By the way, from the photo, the existing wiring looks like it could be the (very) old rubber insulated type of cable, which you may well need to seriously think about replacing).